# Heroku / SSL Endpoint Not Secure

Tags: ssl, heroku, https

I'm trying to set up SSL on a Heroku app with a custom domain. The app for this example's sake will be live at - example.mydomain.com

When I visit https://example.mydomain.com, sometimes I get the message that the identity is verified, but some resources are not secure, and they could be manipulated. Whatever, I know how to fix that. Problem is that it isn't consistent. I refresh it four times, and it goes away. If I'm not getting that message, it's saying "Identity not verified." When it says this, it's because it has for some reason defaulted to using the Heroku SSL, and is reading the certificate for *.herokuapp.com, which is not my URL.

This inconsistency is only replicable in Google Chrome, Firefox always reads the Heroku SSL.

I've enabled the Heroku SSL Endpoint, I've added my CRT and KEY, and when I run heroku:certs I get the SSL Endpoint. I have CNAME records that point to that endpoint. Those look like this -

```
NAME                        | TTL   | TYPE  | DATA
example     | .mydomain.com | 43200 | CNAME | myendpoint-4235.herokussl.com
www.example | .mydomain.com | 43200 | CNAME | myendpoint-4235.herokussl.com
```

DNS lookups confirm that my subdomain is routing to the SSL Endpoint, why is the wrong certificate being read?

The certificate was purchased through Mediatemple, if that's relevant.